# How to remove User-Agent header on apache commons httpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient

I'm using apache commons httpClient 3.0.1 and by default it sets the user agent to Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0, I know to set a custom value but what I need now its to completly remove the User-Agent header from the request, i know that value comes from DefaultHttpParamsFactory.java

It's there a way to change the behavior of that factory ? or to specify my own factory

Comment: FWIW: Do you know that `HttpClient` 3.x is [at end-of-life](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) and no longer being developed...? It looks like you can do what you want with the newer `HttpClient` stuff, since you can send a `HttpRequest` using `BasicHttpRequest` which is an `AbstractHttpMessage` and offers (amongst other things) [`removeHeader`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html#removeHeader(org.apache.http.Header)). Can't find JavaDocs for the old `HttpClient` on two seconds searching, though...

Comment: 3.x (could not find specific 3.0.1 doc) says there is a removeRequestHeader in the HttpMethod interface.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö I have tried `post.removeRequestHeader("User-Agent")`  and `post.removeParameter(HttpClientParams.USER_AGENT)` but those didn't change anything

Comment: You can specify your own factory by calling `DefaultHttpParams.setHttpParamsFactory` in some initialization code somewhere and pass in your subclass. I don't think this will help you though since the default `addUserAgentRequestHeader` method implementation provided by `HttpMethodBase` sends a hard coded value if it finds a `null`. You will have to do what Jukka Zitting suggests for the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to subclass the method and override the [addUserAgentRequestHeader](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-legacy/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpMethodBase.html#addUserAgentRequestHeader%28org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpState,%20org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection%29) method. Something like this:

```
public class NoUserAgentGetMethod extends GetMethod {

    public NoUserAgentGetMethod(String uri) {
        super(uri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void addUserAgentRequestHeader(
            HttpState state, HttpConnection connection) {
        // do nothing
    }

}
```

As you noticed, you can only change the user agent value but not remove it entirely by modifying the parameters. This is because the HttpMethodBase class uses `"Jakarta Commons-HttpClient"` as the hard-coded default if no user agent value has been provided as a parameter.

Note that as mentioned in comments above, switching to the updated [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) codebase of the new [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) project would be a good idea going forward.